# Issue in applying lazyload for images in @Editable

Tags: glass-mapper

A Glassmapper is used in our running project and planning to apply lazy loading for all images.
For this, I have to implement the `renderField` Pipeline to apply lazyload functionality to all images.

It is working fine with the default Sitecore field

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(LandingPage.FieldIds.BackgroundImage.ToString(), Model.LandingPage.Item, new { MaxWidth = 1500 })
```

We are trying to apply lazyloading with Glassmapper. so we have written the below code.

```
@Html.Glass().Editable(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { MaxWidth = 1500 })
```

The above code is working fine in the Experience editor but not working on actual normal page.

How we can apply lazyloading with Glassmapper `@Html.Glass().Editable()` for image field?
Or is there any way to render `renderfield` pipeline for the image field forcefully?

current output with *glass().Editable()*:

```
<img src="/-/media/images/instron/landing-page-images/mastheads/products/webmasthead_testingsystems_2020.jpg?h=382&amp;w=1500&amp;la=en-IN&amp;hash=89A18D0E8314CC8697DCA3BC8C93BDB7" maxwidth="1500" alt="demo">
```

Expected output with *glass().Editable()*:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="demo" width="1500" height="382" maxwidth="1500" data-src="/-/media/images/instron/landing-page-images/mastheads/products/webmasthead_testingsystems_2020.jpg?h=382&amp;iar=0&amp;w=1500&amp;hash=0A90A8CF5873BDA7CBFA8507EDF073C6" class="lazy">
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Manish, Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. Did you try rendering image like this @Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { loading = "Lazy" }, isEditable: true)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is you can now use the loading attribute to lazy-load images without the need to write custom lazy-loading code or use a separate JavaScript library. eg, `<img loading=lazy>`

https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/

Now to render an image using Glass Mapper you should use *RenderImage*

```
@Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { MaxWidth = 1500, loading = "Lazy" }, isEditable: true)
```

Or if want to use *Editable*

```
 @Html.Glass().Editable(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { MaxWidth = 1500, loading= "lazy" })
```

Still, if you want to use class parameter on image tag for lazy loading:

```
@Html.Glass().Editable(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { MaxWidth = 1500, class = "lazy" })
```

Comment: loading= "lazy" is not working in safari browser.   
   @Html.Glass().Editable(Model.LandingPage, x => x.Background_Image, new { MaxWidth = 1500, class = "lazy" })    and if I am using class level lazy loading then I must have to use data-src instead of src.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
@Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, x => x.LandingPage, new { Width = 100 }, isEditable: true)
```

Comment: I have tried with @RenderImage() but it doesn't work